# Z3 bitvector operations

Tags: z3, smt, bitvector

How does one use the 'repeat' and 'rotate_left' bitvector operations?

More generally, where can I find detailed documentation of bitvector operations in the SMT2 scripting format used by Z3?

Everything I find seems to just go to tutorials, or broken links:
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Documentation
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/old/documentation.html

Trying to understand "repeat", "rotate_left", and "rotate_right" by guessing has been frustating. I cannot figure out how to use them.  For example

```
(display (repeat #b01))
(display (repeat #b01 3))
(display (repeat 3))
(display (rotate_left #b0001 2))
```

gives

```
"repeat expects one non-zero integer parameter"
"repeat expects one argument"
"operator is applied to arguments of the wrong sort"
"rotate left expects one argument"
```

Where is the documentation?  Hoping they didn't explain because all of this is standard, I also looked at smt-lib.org but that doesn't list these details either. So frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to dejvuth's answer:

The SMT language is well documented (see smt-lib.org), for this particular issue the [FixedSizeBitVectors theory](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FixedSizeBitVectors.shtml) and the [QF_BV logic](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics-all.shtml#QF_BV) definition are relevant. The latter contains the definition for repeat:

```
((_ repeat i) (_ BitVec m) (_ BitVec i*m))
- ((_ repeat i) x) means concatenate i copies of x
```

Apart from those, David Cok wrote an excellent [SMT2 tutorial](https://www.lri.fr/~conchon/TER/2013/2/SMTLIB2.pdf).

The names of functions in the Z3 API is the same as in SMT2 where syntax permits, in this case prefixed with Z3_mk_ to indicate that they are functions that construct Z3 expressions.

Comment: And in just three months, two out of those three links have been broken.

Comment: Links have been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, you should write something like this

```
(declare-const a (_ BitVec 2))
(declare-const b (_ BitVec 6))
(assert (= a #b01))
(assert (= b ((_ repeat 3) a)))

(declare-const c (_ BitVec 4))
(declare-const d (_ BitVec 4))
(assert (= c #b0001))
(assert (= d ((_ rotate_left 2) c)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

You will get

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun d () (_ BitVec 4)
    #x4)
  (define-fun c () (_ BitVec 4)
    #x1)
  (define-fun b () (_ BitVec 6)
    #b010101)
  (define-fun a () (_ BitVec 2)
    #b01)
)
```

A good document that I usually use is its [API](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/index.html).

Comment: As dejvuth shows, repeat is a parametric function, i.e., there is a parameter on it, not an argument, and the SMT2 syntax for that is (_ ... ). The same applies to many other functions and sorts like (_ BitVec ...).

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Thank you. I had no idea why the tutorials did stuff (_ BitVec 4), because that isn't explained in any of the documents I could find.  Where did you learn this?

Comment: @dejvuth I don't get it.  How did you figure that out from the API links? Searching for repeat I see things like "Z3_OP_REPEAT Repeat bit-vector n times." which give no details , and things like `Z3_mk_repeat (__in Z3_context c, __in unsigned i, __in Z3_ast t1)` which I never would have guessed means the usage in scripts is like "((_ repeat 3) a)".

Comment: Unfortunately, the API is all I have. (Probably @christoph can help you more.) Anyway, the API can be used indirectly to learn the syntax, e.g. `Context ctx = new Context(); BoolExpr be = ctx.mkEq(d, ctx.mkBVRotateLeft(2, c)); System.out.println(be);`, where `d` and `c` are `BitVecExpr`. I know it's not ideal ...